# Careers cover letter bug

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

When I try to apply for some jobs in Careers, it doesn't matter how much I try to change it, the cover letter is always the same as a previous one I submitted for a different vacancy. This is really annoying because I cannot send the same text and now I cannot apply for this job.

Using Mac OS 10.6.8 with Safari 5.1.7.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for reporting, this is definitely a problem. We're looking into this and will provide an update shortly.

Comment: Apollo, can you check if it works now?

Comment: Please let us know if this is still a problem.